# Bootstrap 3, how to right align button on the navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I host [coding and preview](http://bootply.com/81742) here.

I would like to right-align my 2nd button, please show me how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: to the right side of the menu?

Comment: I wish to have the 2nd button to be on the right side on the navbar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check [demo](http://bootply.com/81747)

```
.navbar-header{
  margin-left:5px;
  width:100%;
}
```

And add

> pull-right

class to your button.

Comment: But then the last buttons has no space between the second to last button. Why bootstrap, why?

Comment: @trusktr I think there is no buil-in option in bootstrap, you have to add custom style ``.navbar-btn {
  margin-right:6px;
}``

Comment: This answer is very bad! Doesn't fix any problems

Answer (score 19):

For Bootstrap 3, `.navbar-right` does just that.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
.
.
</ul>
```

Comment: Tried this in Bootstrap v4 alpha and `navbar-right` does not work for me. Adding `pull-right` to `ul` does work.

Answer (score 11):

Within the **navbar** in case of Bootstrap alignment happens a little differently.

For aligning elements to the right in the **navbar** put the required elements in a separate **div** and within it create a **ul** and add the required elements to the list.

To the **div** add a class **.pull-right** to align the elements right.

Sample Code:

```
<div class="pull-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><button type="submit" class="btn navbar-btn btn-danger" name="logout" id="logout"  value="Log Out">Log Out</button></li>
        </ul>     
</div>
```

If there are alignment issues with elements on the left of the **navbar** and a class **.pull-left** to that div

Comment: Only answer that worked. <div class="pull-left">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li><a href="#"> something1</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div> 
          <div class="pull-right">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">            
                  <li><a href="#">LogOut&nbsp</a></li>
              </ul>                
          </div>

Comment: best solution so far

Answer (score 6):

A DEMO [HERE](http://bootply.com/81745)

Well, make that change.

```
.navbar-header{
  width:100%;
}
```

Then place a class on the button that you want to put on the right side, for example `right-side-button`

then apply that class to the `a` and edit in css that way:

```
.right-side-button{
  float:right;
}
```

And you are done!